# Remove lines that contain a certain character but not at the end nor start in BASH

Tags: bash

I need to remove line of a file that contain a "+" but only if it is encased in text, meaning if it's at the start or end it must not be removed.

File:

```
Hello
World
gol+d
fi+sh
+foo
bar+
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
+foo
bar+
```

I've tried using sed '/-/d' , however this deletes all words that have a "+" next to them and leaves ones with the "+" in the middle, the opposite to my intended result.

Trying to find the fastest solution to the problem. Can this be done using grep or sed preferably, but any solution would be great thanks.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.   Your question is off topic, you are lucky I did not flag it for closure.  We will **help** you work on something, not provide you with code if you did not try anything.  There are many reference sites to learn from, SO is not one of them.  Please don't ask questions if your not going to learn how to use the tool prior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These simple 3 conditions of `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/^+/ || /+$/ || !/+/'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Checking here if any line is starting from `+` by doing `/^+/` OR any line is ending with `+` y doing `+$` OR any line is not having `+` by doing `!/+/` then no action mentioned in `awk` so by default print of current line will happen(which will print the current line).

Output will be as follows.

```
Hello
World
+foo
bar+
```

Comment: using this method returns an error message for me: 
awk: illegal primary in regular expression +$ at $
 source line number 1
 context is
 /^+/ || >>>  /+$/ <<<

Comment: try `gawk` instead of `awk`

Comment: @BetaByte, you haven't mentioned on which box you are? so if you are on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk. Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sorry, I'm very new to bash and its just so different to anything else I've used before, I don't really know what I'm doing. What do you mean by "which box you are" and how do I check this for you!

Comment: @BetaByte, type `uname -a` in your system, DO NOT post hostname or IP address here but you could see your O.S name and version there.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0 is this what your looking for?

Comment: @BetaByte, sorry I don't have Darwin OS with me and this code works fine for my bash system but let me know if any ither help I could do it, cheers !!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 got it working now, thanks a lot for the help, it didn't like the +$ for some reason so I've changed it to another character.

Comment: @BetaByte, `+$` means `+` at last of line so not sure what you have changed to, do share with us so that other people could learn from it too, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne 'print if not /^.+\+.+$/' input_file
```

to test

```
perl -ne 'print if not /^.+\+.+$/' input_file >output_file
```

to create an output file

```
perl -ni -e 'print if not /^.+\+.+$/' file
```

To let perl fix the file in place

-n tells perl not to print the line unless you tell it to.  The regex is `^` beginning of line, `.+` one or more of any character, `\+` literal +, `$` end of line.  You may want to replace the `.` in `.+` with a more specific character like "any alphanumeric character" or something if that better meets your requirements.  You can google perl special characters.

sed is easier for this, but I'm honestly not sure how to do it without leaving blank lines around.